# Recycler view item fadeout animation while scrolling

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

currently i'm working on an android project using java, 
Actually i want to make The Map filter fade out on scroll so it doesn't stop randomly.

this is the default animation.[image]

this is what i want to achieve, fadeout/fadein animation depending on scrolling orientation.[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you have just to add the attribute requiresFadingEdge and if you want to specify the length of the transparency you can add another attribute fadingEdgeLength.
Good luck for your project.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```